# What's the difference between T(V) and ImT?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Assuming I have the following Linear transformation:

$\mathbb{T}: \mathbb{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{W}$ where $\mathbb {V}$ and $\mathbb {W}$ are vector space.

`My question is`: What is the difference between writing $\mathbb {T(V)}$ and writing Im$\mathbb {T}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you should had written $T:V\to W$.

There is no difference. $${\rm Im}(T)=\{w\in W\mid \exists v\in V, T(v)=w\}\subseteq W.$$ Also, $$T(V)=\{T(v); v\in V\}\subseteq W.$$

So, both are the same subset of $W$.